# logic errors when writing/reading a file in c

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, file-io, logic

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


static calcNext(struct test input[], int amount);
struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};
struct device
{
    char deviceDescription[26];
    int serial;
};
struct test
{
    char testDescription[26];
    int monthsBetween;
    struct date recent;
    struct date next;
};

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;
    struct device info[30];
    struct test input[30];
    struct test serialResult[30];
    struct device dateResult[30];
    int amount, stop = 0, cont = 0, i, decider, search, searchAmount, day, month, year;
    
    
    while (stop != 1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("\n1. Input data and save to file\n2. Search for a specific device in the file using its serial number and display\n3. Search for a specific date and display all devices that have to be tested on this date\n4. Exit\n\n");
        scanf(" %d", &decider);

        switch (decider)
        {

        case 1:
            while (cont != 1)
            {
                printf("please enter the amount devices you wish to enter (between 1 and 30) :");
                scanf(" %d", &amount);
                if (amount < 1 || amount > 30)
                {
                    printf("please re-enter a valid number");
                }
                else
                {
                    cont++;
                }
            }

            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                printf("please enter the device description \n");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", &info[i].deviceDescription);
                printf("please enter the serial number \n");
                scanf(" %d", &info[i].serial);
                printf("please enter the test description \n ");
                scanf(" %[^\n]s", &input[i].testDescription);
                printf("please enter the months between tests \n");
                scanf(" %d", &input[i].monthsBetween);
                printf("please enter the day of the most recent test\n ");
                scanf(" %d", &input[i].recent.day);
                printf("please enter the month of the most recent test\n ");
                scanf(" %d", &input[i].recent.month);
                printf("please enter the year of the most recent test\n ");
                scanf(" %d", &input[i].recent.year);
                input[i].next.day = input[i].recent.day;
                input[i].next.month = input[i].recent.month;
                input[i].next.year = input[i].recent.year;
                calcNext(input, amount);
            }

            if ((fp = fopen("project.dat", "wb+")) == NULL)
            {
                printf("Couldn't open file to write\n");
            };
            fwrite(info, sizeof(struct device), amount, fp);
            fwrite(input, sizeof(struct test), amount, fp);
            fclose(fp);

            break;

        case 2:
            printf("please enter the serial number of the device you wish to search for :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &search);
            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                if (info[i].serial == search)
                {
                    searchAmount = i;
                    fp = fopen("project.dat", "rb");
                    fseek(fp, searchAmount, 0);
                    fread(&serialResult[i], sizeof(input), 1, fp);
                    fclose(fp);
                    printf("\n%s\t%d\trecent test: %d %d %d\tnext test: %d %d %d", serialResult[i].testDescription, serialResult[i].monthsBetween, input[i].recent.day, input[i].recent.month, input[i].recent.year, input[i].next.day, input[i].next.month, input[i].next.year);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (info[i].serial != search)
                    {
                        printf("\nthis serial number doesnt exist");
                    }
                }
            }
            

            break;

        case 3:
            printf("please enter the day you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &day);
            printf("please enter the month you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &month);
            printf("please enter the year you wish search :\n");
            scanf(" %d", &year);
            for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
            {
                if (input[i].recent.day == day & input[i].recent.month == month & input[i].recent.year == year)
                {
                    searchAmount = i;
                    fp = fopen("project.dat", "rb");
                    fseek(fp, searchAmount, 0);
                    fread(&dateResult[i], sizeof(input), 1, fp);
                    fclose(fp);
                    printf("\n %s\t%d", dateResult[i].deviceDescription, dateResult[i].serial);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (input[i].recent.day != day & input[i].recent.month != month & input[i].recent.year != year)
                    {
                        printf("\nthis date doesnt exist");
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            break;

        case 4:
            return 0;
            break;

        default:
            printf("An invalid option was selected!\n\n");
        }
    }
    

    
}

static calcNext(struct test input[], int amount)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        
        input[i].next.month = input[i].recent.month + input[i].monthsBetween;
        if (input[i].next.month > 12)
        {
            input[i].next.month - 12;
            input[i].next.year + 1;
        }
    }
    
    return(input);
}
```

having issues with logic in regards to case 2 and 3 when it comes to reading the file I have created in this program.  i know that the for loop is causing the error when it comes to printing the fail safe printf statement. but im having difficulty figuring out the correct logic of the statements.  the program works fine when you only input one set of data but when multiple sets are inputed, then errors occur because of the for loops looping more then one time. if this doesnt make sense please comment and i will provide further detail as i find it difficult to explain.

Comment: Please don't forget the *minimal* part of your [mcve]. Do we really need to see the whole program to understand the problem?

Comment: Possibly related to your problem: `fseek(fp, searchAmount, 0);` The offset to seek to is in *bytes* not "elements". Perhaps you should use `searchAmount * sizeof(input)`?

Comment: Your file format is unusable. Since the number of devices isn't saved in the file, there's no way to know where the `device` structures end and the `test` structures begin.

Comment: Instead of writing all the devices followed by all the tests, you could alternate them.

Comment: There's no reason to keep opening, seeking, and closing. Just read the structures in a loop until you find the serial number you want.

Comment: i understand what you are saying, how would u suggest i alternate them? @Barmar

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) { fwrite(&info[i], sizeof(struct device), 1, fp); fwrite(&input[i], sizeof(struct test), 1, fp); }`

Comment: Then in case 2 you have to alternate reading the two structures.

Comment: ive seemed to get case 2 to be working, but case 3 is still giving incorrect info